# mysql to check Instructor is available for lesson at selected time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lesson booking calendar and I am trying to check if the Instructor is booked at given time or is available.

I have following table for saving `lesson_registrations`

```
| id | InstructorId | startTime    | endTime      |
|  1 | 2            | 201806271100 | 201806271200 |
|  2 | 2            | 201806271400 | 201806271500 |
```

So according to this table Instructor is available for a lesson between `201806271200` to `201806271400` but when I run the following query it marks the Instructor to be booked.

```
SELECT * FROM lesson_registrations 
WHERE 
((startTime BETWEEN '201806271200' AND '201806271400' ) 
 OR (endTime BETWEEN '201806271200' AND '201806271400') 
 OR ('201806271200' BETWEEN startTime AND endTime) 
 OR ('201806271400' BETWEEN startTime AND endTime) )
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that because between is inclusive the statement is catching the records with 201806271200 as endtime.
If you run the following you get no results showing that there are lessons available.

```
SELECT * FROM lesson_registrations
WHERE 
(startTime BETWEEN '201806271159' AND '201806271359' )
```

yea 1200 counts as the end time so the start time of the next needs to be in 1201 or the endtime needs to be in 1159 and the start time can be 1200

Answer (score 0):

The correct logic for finding any overlaps would be:

```
select lr.*
from lesson_registrations lr
where lr.startTime < 201806271400 and
      lr.endTime > 201806271200;
```

To get instructors who *are* avaialable:

```
select i.*
from instructors i
where not exists (select 1
                  from lesson_registrations lr
                  where lr.instructorId = i.instructorId and
                        lr.startTime < 201806271400 and
                        lr.endTime > 201806271200
                 );
```

The logic basically says that an instructor is not available if the following two conditions are true:

- The a lesson starts any time before the end time.
- The same lesson ends any time after the start time.